# Magento 2 - Invoice without collecting shipping cost

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice, virtual-products, shipping-charges

Is there a way to create a partial invoice without collecting the shipping cost?

For example, if I have an order with a virtual product and a shipped product, I want to be able to invoice the virtual product first without collecting the shipping.

Digging through code I don't see a way to do this built-in to magento.

Are there any mods that do this?  Or suggestions on where to start if I were to write a mod to provide this functionality.

Comment: Can't answer my own post but i did this with extension attributes and a plugin.  My need was specifically for the salesInvoiceOrder API which has an arguments argument.  I added a shipping amount extension attribute there then created a plugin for InvoiceDocumentFactory on afterCreate to look for that attribute and set the shipping amounts on the invoice.